How do I markup a flash message in Flask?
I was running a Flask application using Python 3.9.13, Flask 1.1.2, Jinja2 2.11.3, and MarkupSafe 1.1.1, using a Redis (3.5.3) as my session store. When I created a flash message with
flash(Markup('<b>This</b> is a <b>WARNING</b>.'),category="warning")
Flask would display (as expected)
This is a WARNING.
with the selected backbrouund color associated with the warning flash messages.
I'm trying to move the application to Python 3.12.4, Flask 3.0.3, and MarkupSafe 2.1.5 (Jinja2 ia at 3.1.4, but Flask moved to use MarkupSafe directly, instead of importing it from Jinja2, so I don't think that's relevant, Redis is 5.0.8). However, when I try to redirect to a page with that set as the flash message, the app fails sliently with an Internal Server Error.
Digging deeply into Flask, I can see that it's throwing an exception Encoding objects of type Markup is unsupported, when it's handling the process_response and trying to save the session https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/src/flask/app.py#L1301, and it seems to be caused by the Markup object in the _flashes list. If convert the Markup to a string, it doesn't fail, but the message is displayed as:
<b>This</b> is a <b>WARNING</b>. (It does display with the correct background color.)
Is there a way to format a flash message in the current Flask like we used to be able to do in earlier versions, or am I doing something wrong?

Is it possible for you to use the jinja filter safe within the template that displays the flash messages? {{ msg | safe }}

@Detlef, thanks for the suggestion, but the error appears to be occurring in Flask's conversion of the Session object to json, not in the template process itself. The _flashes key in the Session object contains the Markup object, so I don't know whether (1) in earlier versions of Flask, there was no such key, (2) earlier versions had such a key, but the Markup object had already been translated to a string, and Flask would properly output it as html, (3) earlier versions had a key, and the Markup object was already there, but Flask properly handled the Markup object.

I thought you could use the Flash message as a string including the HTML tags within the template by bypassing the automatic escaping. In this sense, the markup object only prevents escaping. So you only change the location of the execution.

So the suggestion by @Detlef works. I had to do three things:
(1) call flash with a plain string:
flash('<b>This</b> is a <b>WARNING</b>.',category="warning")

(2) change the jinja template from:
  <div class="container-fluid">
  {%- with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True) %}
  {%- if messages %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-13">
        {{utils.flashed_messages(messages)}}
      </div>
    </div>
  {%- endif %}
  {%- endwith %}
  </div>

to
   {%- with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True) %}
   {%- if messages %}
      {% for category, message in messages %}
      <div class="container-fluid flashed-messages" style="margin-top:1em;padding-left:5em;padding-right:5em">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-13">
               <div class="{{ category }}">{{ message | safe }}</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
   {%- endif %}
   {%- endwith %}

and
(3) make sure my static/css/app.css had the appropriate classes used by the code (which only uses error, message, warning, and success):
.error {
  color: white;
  background-color: red
}

.message {
  color: black;
  background-color: lightblue
}

.warning {
  color: black;
  background-color: orange
}

.success {
  color: white;
  background-color: green
}

This gave me formatted flash messages with the correct background colors. Thank you, @Detlef!
